# LINQ to XML, with conditions and Variable XML Structure with C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, data-structures, linq-to-xml

i have an big issue, and just lost like 5 hours on it.
I have to create an XML file, which will be populated by a database reg.
i have variable structure, which in some cases will use specific sub structure.

the logic is simple.

I have to get all agencys,
 then in every agency i have to iterate a foreach cycle, 
 and get all houses that they whant to sell/rent.
 But its not only houses, there´s apartaments, garages, and so on.
Each of this scenes have their own structure with different data.

This is not all, there must have an condition. Only writes xml childs only if they are supposed to.

piece of xml example

```
<Clients>
    <Client>
        <aggregator/>
        <code/>
        <reference/>
        <contact>
        <secondhandListing>
            <property>
                <code/>
                <reference/>
                <scope/>
                <address>
                <features/>
                <operation>     // variable structure

    1example        <price/>
                    <communityCosts/>

    2example       <price/>
                   <communityCosts/>
                   <depositType/>

                </operation>
            </property>
        </secondhandListing>
```

Can some one show me an example of how this could be done.
what I archive until now was:

```
var agenciasConectores = //query of Agencys

foreach (var agenciaConector in agenciasConectores)
{
    var imoveisAgencia = // query of homes in each Agency

    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        new XElement("Clients",
            from agencia in agenciasConectores
                select new XElement("Client", new XAttribute("ID", agencia.AgencyId),
                new XElement("aggregator", agencia.ConnectorLicense),
                new XElement("code", agencia.Name),
                new XElement("Reference", agencia.Phone),
                new XElement("contact", agencia.Phone),
                new XElement("secondhandListing"),
                new XElement("newbuildListing")
                )));
    foreach (var imovel in imoveisAgencia)
    {
        if (imoveisAgencia.Count() > 1)
        {
            doc.Document.Add(new XElement("property",
                new XElement("code", "codigo"),
                new XElement("reference", "reference"),
                new XElement("scope", "scope"),
                new XElement("address", "address"),
                new XElement("contact", "contact"),
                new XElement("features", "features"),
                new XElement("operation", "operation"),
                new XElement("description", "description")));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What's going wrong with what you're currently doing?

Answer (score 0):

When I try to run this in Visual Studio, the following line throws an exception

```
doc.Document.Add(new XElement("property",
...
```

are you trying to do something more like this?

```
doc.Root.Add(new XElement("property",
...
```

or, perhaps, something closer to this

```
doc.Descendants("Client")
    .Single(c => c.code == "something")
    .Add(new XElement("property",
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Already find a solution.

its simple.

```
XElement root = new XElement("root");
XElement child = new XElement("Child");
XElement child2 = new XElement(Child2);
```

then I populate the elements.

```
Child.SetValue(a);
child2.Setvalue(b);
```

and at final, i just add elements to parent Element.

```
root.add(Child,Child2);
```

But like that i also can make some validations(in my case in cycle)

```
If(a>b)
    root.add(child);
else
    root.add(child2);
```

thx for the try. I learn it by the example hehehhe